# iOS - UIWebview Partial Disappear on Scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I've implemented a custom header view that is not part of a UITableView. However, it responds to scrollView delegate methods to adjust the NSLayoutConstraint constant of it's height. The header view contains a web view that renders a static image. The header view moves on and off the screen as expected during tableView scrolling. When scrolling is fast (up/down) it works as expected. However, if you scroll down slowly the content of the UIWebview disappears.
[image]

I had initially thought it may have something to do with the webView's scrollView.contentSize but that seems to be adjusting correctly (based on NSLog). If you take a look at the above gif, the orange is the background of the UIWebview, so only the actual content of the html is vanishing; the view itself is intact. Anyone else run into this issue?

Relevant code:

```
#define kMaxHeaderHeight 160.0
#define kMinHeaderHeight 0.0
-(void)setupWebview
{
    self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
    self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    NSString *html =
    @"<head>"
    @"<style>"
    @"body {"
    @"padding: 0px;"
    @"font-family: Arial;"
    @"width: 100%;"
    @"margin: 0px;"
    @"text-align: center;"
    @"}"
    @".image {"
    @"position: absolute;"
    @"margin: 0px;"
    @"bottom: 0;"
    @"padding: 0px;"
    @"}"
    @"</style>"
    @"</head>"
    @"<body>"
    @"<a>"
    @"<img class='image' src='http://mgk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/bedbug_ICON.png' />"
    @"</a>"
    @"</body>";

    [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView != self.tableView) return;

    CGFloat scrollDiff = scrollView.contentOffset.y - previousScrollOffset;
    CGFloat absoluteTop = 0.0;
    CGFloat absoluteBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;
    BOOL isScrollingDown = scrollDiff > 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y > absoluteTop;
    BOOL isScrollingUp = scrollDiff < 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y < absoluteBottom;

    CGFloat newHeight = self.headerViewHeightConstraint.constant;
    if (isScrollingDown) {
        newHeight = MAX(kMinHeaderHeight, self.headerViewHeightConstraint.constant - fabs(scrollDiff));
    } else if (isScrollingUp) {
        newHeight = MIN(kMaxHeaderHeight, self.headerViewHeightConstraint.constant + fabs(scrollDiff));
    }

    if (newHeight != self.headerViewHeightConstraint.constant) {
        self.headerViewHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight;
        [self updateScrollPosition:previousScrollOffset];
    } 



    previousScrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}

-(void)updateScrollPosition:(CGFloat)postition
{
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.tableView.contentOffset.x, postition);
}
```

What I've tried:

- forcing the webview to layoutSubviews [self.webView layoutSubViews];
- collecting all subviews of UIWebview into an array and adjust their height as the scrolling happens.
- adjusting the contentView of the webView.scrollView as scrolling happens.
- a bunch of other stuff i can't remember. suggest something and I'll tell you if i've tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP was able to resolve the issue by using WKWebView instead of UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

Can you force the webview to layout when changing the tableView contentOffset?

`[self.webview setNeedsLayout]`

Comment: Thanks for responding @Garfield81. I did try that, didn't work. I'm going to add a list of things I've tried to the OP; I'm starting to think this is an iOS bug.

Comment: Can you try WKWebView instead of UIWebView?

Comment: Great suggestion, @Garfield81. I had to go in add the view programatically and set up all constraints programatically, but WKWebview seems to be the way to go. Thank you. If you'd like to make this an 'Answer' I'll accept it as soon as I can.

Comment: Glad it helped. I have posted the answer.